# The augmentation ideal of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Assume that $R$ is commutative.
Prove that the augmentation ideal in the group ring $RG$ is generated by {$g-1 | g \in G$}. I am having difficulty of knowing what i need to show, and what do i need in order to show something is a generator in ideals.

Answer (score 3):

Just show that those elements are in the ideal, and then show that every element of the ideal is equal to a combination of those specified elements.

Hint 1: You shouldn't have any trouble showing the augmentation ideal (the kernel of the map $\phi:RG\to R$ given by $\phi(\sum r_gg)=\sum r_g$) contains $g-1$ for all $g$. (What does $\phi(g-1)$ evaluate to?)

Hint 2: Conversely, if $\sum r_gg$ is in the kernel of $\phi$, $\phi(\sum r_gg)=\sum r_g=0$. Hint: expand $\sum(g-1)r_g$ to find a connection with $\sum r_gg$.